# How to join different columns of same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have one table with two column, Country and City.

**Country**

```
USA
Canada
UK
```

**City**

```
NY
London
```

I want to join/merge both column records and expect the output like this -

```
USA
Canada
UK
NY
London
```

So, what will be the SQL query to merge different columns records of same table?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Country FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT City FROM Table
```

should do it.

Comment: I am searching for any quick way. Because if I need to merge 10 columns then i have to write 10 Unions! Is there any other way?

Comment: You should probably structure the data in a different way possibly?

Comment: No. Except changing database model

Comment: Lol.. It was a SQL quiz question.

Answer (score 3):

Responding to the comment "I am searching for any quick way. Because if I need to merge 10 columns then i have to write 10 Unions! Is there any other way?":

You can use an unpivot, which means you just need to add the column names into a list. Only thing is to watch for data types though. eg:

```
--CTE for example only
;WITH CTE_Locations as (
    select Country = convert(varchar(50),'USA'), City = convert(varchar(50),'NY')
    union select Country = 'Canada', City = 'Vancouver'
    union select Country = 'UK', City = 'Manchester'
)
--Select a list of values from all columns
select distinct
    Place
from
    CTE_Locations l
    unpivot (Place for PlaceType in ([Country],[City])) u
```